# Is it safe to use triggers in innoDB?

Tags: mysql, triggers, transactions, innodb

Let's put a trigger on the purchase of goods, the trigger withdraws funds from the user's account, it is safe? Whether the transaction is automatically applied to the purchase request and all requests within a trigger?

Comment: shouldn't you be checking if funds are available, rather than just "taking" after the fact?

Comment: Yes, this is just an example, I am interested in is safe to use triggers instead of multiple queries wrapped in a transaction. InndoDB automatically wrap 2 query in one transaction using a trigger?

Comment: (My opinion:)  It is better to have all the activity clearly visible in the transaction, not hiding under the covers in triggers, cascading FK stuff, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always safe to use Triggers irrespective of the database Engine. However if you have a **row based replication** configured and have a trigger after **insert** the lag in the slave will become higher. And the **Slave** will take some time to catch up.

The restrictions and **limitations** on triggers are given in the below link refer the same

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.1/en/stored-program-restrictions.html